# Why does my infulxdb insert a new row of data only every 10 seconds?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I wrote a timed task in c# to insert one row of data per second,
but I found that only one row of data is inserted every 10 seconds.
I also noticed that new insert requests within 10 seconds will only update the same row of data and not insert a new one.
What is the setting that causes this and how do I change it?
The version of influxdb is 2.2, I downloaded it from the website and started it directly without changing any configuration.

Comment: Can you show related code snippet (writing to InfluxDB)?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using query creator which aggregates data (prepares query with aggregation). Example setting in InfluxDB v2 web GUI:

[image: where to change]

Setting period to 1s or writing your own query without any aggregation should solve your problem.

What is more: writing data with the same tag keys to InfluxDB, with the same timestamp and the same value field name will overwrite existing value in InfluxDB. So described behaviour is normal.

Comment: thank you  so much ，that's the setting issue, I have asked the same question at the Official forum,but no one answered.

Comment: @Afowne you should mark this as the answer